# Unable to get mp3 tags from files in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to get mp3 tags from my files that stored in Amazon S3 using Boto.
Here is my script :

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import eyeD3

def main():
conn = S3Connection('______', '_________')
myBucket = conn.get_bucket('bucketName')

for key in skempi.list():
    if eyeD3.isMp3File(key.name):
        audio = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(key.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I could list all the files in my bucket and so on. The error i'm getting is

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'ulver/01 Track 1.mp3'
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write a script that the meta data of the mp3 files from my local drive, uploads the songs to Amazon S3 (Using Boto API) and set privileges to "public", generates a URL, then store the URL and metal data into a MySQL database. So just in case some runs into same problem, this solved my issue as I now don't need to upload the songs and then run an update for my database.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing key.name to the eyeD3 functions but I think you want a file-like object for the call to eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile.  I haven't used eyeD3 and it doesn't seem to want to install via pip so I can't try this but something like this should work:

```
for key in skempi.list():
    if eyeD3.isMp3File(key.name):
        audio = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(key)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work because it requires a String in the parameter. My problem is that I couldn't get the path of each file in my bucket.

Comment: If it requires a string then it must expect that string to be a path to a local file.  In that case, the only option is to copy the file from S3 to your local filesystem (using key.get_contents_to_filename) and then pass the path to the local file to the Mp3AudioFile class.

Comment: Well, I need to get the paths + mp3 metadata of these files to store it in a MySQL database for my Django app, so later I'll be able to play them in on my website. Is there any other library (other than eyeD3) that allows me to read tags from a non-local file?

Comment: I don't, sorry.  If you want the full URL for the MP3 files as stored in S3 you can call key.generate_url(1, query_auth=False, force_http=True) for each key.  This will give you a URL pointing to the object in S3.  Hope that helps.

Comment: That means the files are not publicly readable.  Do you want them to be?  Or are you intended these to be accessible only through your application?  You can create signed URL's that expire in a period of time.  For example, key.generate_url(60, force_http=True) would generate a signed URL that will expire (i.e. become unusable) in 60 seconds.  I don't really know what your application is so I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: I want them to be public forever because I'll use these links to my music player in my web app.

Comment: Then you need to set the ACL of the objects to 'public-read'.  You can do that with key.set_canned_acl('public-read').  Also, when you upload new files, you can specify the ACL when you upload with key.set_contents_from_filename('<filename>', policy='public-read').

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the tags from the files **without** downloading them from S3.

You might consider using EC2 to process the files or [Amazons Elastic MapReduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) but you're still going to be downloading the file to read the tags.

Comment: I'll be running the update (meta data extraction from mp3 files in AS3 and upload the data to MySQL database) from the Django admin panel. So I should download the files temporarely into my server and then get the metadata from them?

Comment: @MohamedTurki - Is this a one-off task? If yes, then I'd write a completely separate script in whatever language you prefer to do the indexing? I wouldn't want to download the files to my web server even if temporarily.

Comment: emm, I'm not sure how frequently I'll be doing this, perhaps once in three months. Problem is, i'll need to fill the database from different sources, AS3 to get the url of each mp3 file, and from local drive to get metatags of the same mp3 file. Maybe I'm not giving this task as much attention as it deserves, as I thought it wouldn't be this complicated, maybe I should write a script that uploads files and extract metal data at the same time? Is that feasible?

Comment: @MohamedTurki I would absolutely go down the route of 'indexing' the files during the upload process. S3 buckets can be somewhat difficult to manage with lots of files if you don't already have a firm grip of what's in there. This should be easy to implement. Upload to your server, extract the tags and add to DB along with any other info about file (incuding details of S3 location eg bucket subfolder etc in case you want to move some files in time), move to S3. If your server is in EC2 then this is even better as transfers between EC2 and S3 are free and very fast.